# Keeping terms separate without combining it especially with multiplied random numbers

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

Suppose I have an expression where random numbers in exponentials are multiplied and this expression will keep on iterating such that more of such terms will occur. But I need to keep those terms as separate instances since each of them contains a separate random number. Although `HoldForm[]` keeps the expression from being evaluated but it doesn't solve the problem.

For example, I have this `Exp[RandomReal[]]^2`, but I need this
`Exp[RandomReal[]]*Exp[RandomReal[]]`, without getting multiplied into  whole squared form.

Thanks, in advance for helping.

Comment: `Inactivate[Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]], Times]`?

Comment: ... or `Inactivate[Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]], Times|Exp]`?

Comment: Thanks, kglr! It worked.

Comment: posted the comments as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html?q=Inactivate)  the functions `Times` or both `Times` and `Exp`:

```
Inactivate[Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]], Times] (* or *)
Inactivate[Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]] Exp[RandomReal[]], Times|Exp]
```

[image]